# java.lang.RuntimeException and unable to instantiate

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine, runtimeexception

I've tried to find the solution to this, but it looks right to my n00b eyes so I'm completely lost.  I've tried looking for other problems and they all seem to have different answers so their no help at all.  And this is some sample code that I'm trying to get working so I apologize for the odd naming.

I'm getting this error

```
09-30 17:22:26.467: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 17:22:26.467: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{test.test/test.test.test.splashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.test.test.splashScreen in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/test.test-1.apk]
```

And this is my Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
package="test.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".test.splashScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".test.Game" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground"/>
    <activity android:name=".test.test" />
    <activity android:name=".test.TMXTiledMapExampleAStar" />
    <activity android:name=".test.Options" />
    <activity android:name=".test.MainMenu" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

And this is the beginning of the splashScreen file

```
package test.test.test;

public class splashScreen extends BaseGameActivity {
```

Comment: Okay... I'm looking at it.  What am I looking for?  I've looked it over and it looks right so I must not know the bug that's causing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, give more intuitive names to your packages!
I would prefer to comment, but I have not enough rep.

2 suggestions:

Try cleaning your project

Try:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="test.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
```

and

```
<activity android:name=".splashScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
```

Comment: Yeah... that didn't work at all.  I'm still getting the same error. And I don't see any difference in the <manifest> you suggested.